# Is there any direct way/method to verify whether a Tweet exists or not?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twython

I need a method that returns only `True` if a Tweet exists, and otherwise, returns `False` without using `statuses_look()` or try-except, as I don't want it to fetch all the data first just to see if it exists.

**E.g.:** what I want to achieve:

```
id = '1287710013964931072'
if api.is_valid_status_id(id): #build-in method or simply creating my own function.
    process_data(id)
```

#### But not like...

```
id = '1287710013964931072'
try :
    status = api.get_status(id)
    process_data(id)
except:
    pass
```

or

```
id = ['1287710013964931072']
for status in api.statuses_lookup(id):
    process_data(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, a valid ID doesn't necessarily correspond with a Tweet on Twitter, and there's no way to know whether it does or not without checking. The direct method would be to make a request to Twitter's API to determine if the ID represents an existing Tweet.